# Sudden Increase of Lotus Mail File

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

Currently, the domino server is configured as clustered and replicated. Currently, the cluster is Active-Active. One of my clients reported his email which is connected to Server 2 increased suddenly exceeding his mail quota. I've increased the mail quota after reported but the problem re-occurred again..I've temporarily connect him to Server 1 to use Lotus Notes. I've backup and deleted his mail in Server 2 then created another replica to Server 2, yet after a day it occurred again.

I would like to ask if you can have another suggestion. I have also check his mail rules and settings.

I do notice when opening his mail file in Lotus Domino, they are different template look but have the same mail version.

Updated:

Example screenshot.

http://imageshack.com/a/img911/3413/VTQysJ.jpg
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/5989/mfnWi0.jpg

Comment: Where does the size of the mailfile come from: data, design, or view indices?

Comment: Is it possible that one server in the cluster has DAOS enabled and the other does not?

Comment: I'm pretty sure and double check, DAOS is disabled. I've checked his documents in mail files, Server 1 has 7500 mails while Server 2 has 35000 mails. Even though I've tried already steps given below by Sir BastianW. Still the same output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following might be the issue:
Server 1 has no deletion rights on Server 2. Therefore deleted elements couldn´t be synced. The best way would be to add a group with both servers to the ACL with Manager Access. THIS by the way seamed to be the correct solution as you mentioned the different design. If the design is different on both servers it looks like either of the server hasn´t the needed rights to replicate the design. So to fix that do the following:

1. Delete the mailfile replica on the users PC (to ensure no shit is coming back)
2. Delete the mailfile on server 2
3. Change the ACL on Server 1. Add a group which contains both servers to the ACL. Make sure the group has manager access with delete rights.
4. Create a replica on Server 2

   5. Create a new replica on the users PC (if he has a replica).

Possible other solutions:
- Server 1 has DAOS activated and Server 2 not

- The user is using a local replica but changed it, so that the deleted emails will not be transfered back to the server. In various situations when the replication history is removed all the stuff the user had locally is replicated back. Best solution I have done here in the past. Delete the local mailfile from the user. Delete the replica on server 2. Reset the replication history on server 1. Create the replica on server 2 and on the the users notebook (tell him to use an real archive instead of doing such a kind of shit)

Comment: I think it continuously replicate with its Lotus Notes. But when I browse the his mail file there are none duplicate entries..

Comment: I will be providing a sample screenshot.

Comment: And did you checked the solution mentioned here? Is the ACL from the mailfile correct? That means are BOTH servers in it with full access?

Comment: Yes the ACL is correct. Sorry I missed the first step, to check his local replica mail. Now is under control again. Thank you Sir BastianW.

Comment: great to hear you got it solved.